# Setting up DNS in WHM/cPanel

Tags: domain-name-system, glue-record

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, but I'm sure this is a simple fix.  I setup WHM/cPanel for the first time on my VPS and understand how DNS works for the most part (or so I thought).

I created under the main domain name 2 nameservers (ns1.maindomain.com & ns2.maindomain.com). I have 2 IP address for my sever so each one points to a unique IP:

```
ns1.maindomain.com => 198.x.x.204
ns2.maindomain.com => 198.x.x.205
```

I also set up reverse DNS with my hosting provider. When I put in my two nameservers under another domain (secondary domain), GoDaddy states that the nameservers are invalid.

Any ideas on why this is or any configurations in cPanel that need to be made?

Comment: Admin panels are [off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (see [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258) for some reasons). The community has decided that we want to close both old and new questions when such an admin panel is relevant ([link 1](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8086), [link 2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to login into the control panel for whoever you registered your domain name with and look for a way to 'Register Nameservers' or create 'Child Nameservers'.  This will create the proper GLUE records so that you can actually use those nameservers and IPs as nameservers for DNS.

If you are using GoDaddy, here is a support page that outlines how to do it with them.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/668/registering-your-own-nameservershosts

Answer (score 0):

> I also set up reverse DNS with my hosting provider.

This is a totally different concept to nameservers. Reverse DNS is the process of taking an IP (e.g. `1.2.3.4`) and making `example.com` out of it; you want the other way around.

To fix this, to your *domain registrar* and look for a "child nameservers", "child hosts" (or similar) option - and register your nameservers with your IPs there.

After that, GoDaddy will accept them.